# Расстановка слов в предложении

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно расставить слова в предложении:

1. Прошу предоставить возможность моему представителю ознакомиться...
2. Прошу предоставить моему представителю возможность ознакомиться...

Заранее благодарен.
С уважением, Юрий.

Comment: Было бы правильно дать фразу полностью. Заранее спасибо за понимание.

Comment: прошу предоставить моему представителю - Иванову Ивану Ивановичу, паспорт серии 0000 №0000, выдан 0000, проживающему по адресу: 0000 - возможность ознакомиться 23.12.2020 в Городском суде с материалами гражданского дела №0000 по иску 0000 к 0000 с использованием средств фотографирования.

Comment: или, например,  так

Comment: прошу предоставить возможность моему представителю - Иванову Ивану Ивановичу, паспорт серии 0000 №0000, выдан 0000, проживающему по адресу: 0000 - ознакомиться 23.12.2020 в Городском суде с материалами гражданского дела №0000 по иску 0000 к 0000 с использованием средств фотографирования.

Comment: мне больше нравится второй вариант, но написал как в первом

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта допустимы, но *второй* выглядит естественнее, поскольку не разбивает на части "**возможность ознакомиться**", предоставляемую представителю. Схема получается простой и ясной: "**предоставить кому что**". А в первом случае смысл такой же, но конструкция сложнее для восприятия: возникает ощущение, что *возможность* предоставляется *лично просителю* и состоит она в том, чтобы его представитель мог ознакомиться, однако *явно* это не выражено.